# How do I prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{n}(\sin^{-1}(\frac{i}{n})-\sin^{-1}(\frac{i-1}{n}))$ converges to $1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i-1}{n}(\sin^{-1}(\frac{i}{n})-\sin^{-1}(\frac{i-1}{n}))$ converges to $1$?

Comment: Try using a telescoping series to simplify it.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, the $i$-th term contains $(i-1)\sin^{-1}\frac in$ and the next term contains $i\left(-\sin^{-1}\frac in\right)$. Adding them gives $-\sin^{-1}\frac in$. So the sum simplifies to 
$$\frac 1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(-\sin^{-1}\frac in\right)+(n-1)\sin^{-1}\frac nn\right)=-\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin^{-1}\frac in+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac \pi2 $$
The first summand is a Riemann sum of $\sin^{-1}x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ with left endpoints. And the second summand converges to $\pi/2$. Thus, the limit is 
$$\frac\pi 2-\int_0^1\sin^{-1}x\,dx=1 $$